# Complex conjugate of the logarithm of the hyperbolic tangent

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

Given the Schwarz reflection principle, I would aytomaticaly write down that the complex conjugate of the following function: $$ ln[tanh(z)] $$, where z is a complex number, is: $$ln[tanh(\bar{z})] $$. Nevertheless, the result I got from Mathematica, is totally different: $$ln[-itan(z)] $$. How can this be correct? Can conjugation change the function?

Comment: You might want to look up the exponential function representations for both the tangent and hyperbolic tangent, to help you decide.

Comment: Well, we have that $$tan(z)=-i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}} $$ and $$tanh(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{e^{z}+e^{-z}} $$ which actually shows that: $$tanh(z)=-itan(iz) $$ Regarding now the complex conjugate, $$ \bar{tanh(z)}=\bar{-itan(iz)}=itan(\bar{iz})=itan(-i\bar{z})=\frac{e^{\bar{z}}-e^{-\bar{z}}}{e^{\bar{z}}+e^{-\bar{z}}}$$ which is what i would expect through: $$\bar{tanh(z)}=tanh(\bar{z})=\frac{e^{\bar{z}}-e^{-\bar{z}}}{e^{\bar{z}}+e^{-\bar{z}}} $$ So the first guess seems correct. But why mathematica gave the other result?

Comment: For reference: can you include the exact input you gave to *Mathematica*?

Comment: Sure: For the complex number "1+i", i had: 
In: Conjugate[Log[Tanh[1+i]]]
Out: Log[-iTanh[1+i]]

Comment: So it gave me actually that $$ \bar{tanh(z)}=-itan(z) $$

Comment: Notice the result of `Log[Tanh[1 - I]]`.

Comment: Yes, the result of this is:Log[-i Tan[1 + i]]'

Comment: That's a big logical jump you're taking. Try this: `ComplexExpand[Log[Conjugate[Tanh[z]]] - Log[Tanh[Conjugate[z]]], z] // FullSimplify`. Also, consider what happens when $z$ is a negative number.

Comment: It gives me zero.. So this is $$Log(\bar{tanh(z)})=Log(tanh(\bar{z})) $$in the end as I have seen by hand above, right?

Comment: And what is the huge logical jump? I am a beginner in Mathematica but I did not see that coming. From the ComplexExpand code result, I see that it is indeed $$ \bar{tanh(z)}=tanh(\bar{z})$$, correct?

Comment: The "logical jump" was when you guessed based on evaluation at a single point. But yes, in general, meromorphic functions like the hyperbolic tangent satisfy the relationship $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$. The logarithm is **not** meromorphic, however. Which brings me back to my request that you try $-z$ to prove or disprove your conjecture.

Comment: Well, I understand. I used therefore the command:

**ComplexExpand[Log[Conjugate[Tanh[-z]]] - Log[Tanh[Conjugate[-z]]], z]**, (where I replaced the "z" with "-z" except for the last "z" of the command) and I got again zero. So I suppose this proves that $$Log(\bar{tanh(z)})=Log(tanh(\bar{z}))$$, indeed. Is the use of the command correct so I can trust the result?

Comment: Yes, I think that after seeing that the "-z" Complex expand gives Zero, this conjecture is indeed correct.  In case I am mistaken, please tell me, I am really happy that you helped me learn this caveat. I am also happy for realizing this logical step in terms of Mathematica, it was really helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Nevertheless, how can this result mean: $$\Big[Log[tanh(z)]\Big]^{*}=Log[(tanh(z))^{*}]$$??

The previous result from the complex expand is more or less trivial, as we know that the $tanh(z)$ is meromorphic..

Comment: The (principal) logarithm isn't meromorphic.

Comment: Which means that the result: $$\Big[Log(tanh(z))\Big]^{*}=Log(tanh(\bar{z})) $$

is correct or wrong? in the end, because I am really confused, what is the conjugate of this full function?(for general z)

Comment: Well, I used the following code:

`ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Log[Tanh[z]]]]+ComplexExpand[Log[Tanh[z]]]`

and the result I got is:

 `Log[Tanh[z]^2]`

Therefore, I conclude that: $$Log(\text{tanh}(z))+c.c=Log((\text{tanh}(z))^{2}) $$

Do you find this approach correct? In terms of Mathematica?